# MvcSiteMapNodeProvider with security trimming enabled throws sql exception

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, mvcsitemapprovider

When I run my MVC5 EF6 MSSQL 2012 application I receive the following exception.

[image: excetption]

I tracked the issue down to a line in my config

```
<add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_SecurityTrimmingEnabled" value="true" />
```

Once I remove this line, my site builds properly, but off course security trimming is off so now my menus are broken.

The whole appSettings section is as follows

```
<appSettings>
<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="SkipApplicationAuthorizationRole" value="Developer" />
<add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_UseExternalDIContainer" value="false" />
<add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_ScanAssembliesForSiteMapNodes" value="false" />
<add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_IncludeAssembliesForScan" value="Triton.Web" />
<add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_SecurityTrimmingEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_AttributesToIgnore" value="type" />
<add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_DefaultSiteMapNodeVisibiltyProvider" value="MvcSiteMapProvider.FilteredSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider, MvcSiteMapProvider" />
<add key="mvc" />
<add key="Twilio.Sid" value="PNf8944dec9bf751ad111f87e1a7ece2b3" />
<add key="Twilio.Token" value="2d1a16e5f7109c56307cc6b696ff1de4" />
<add key="Twilio.Phone" value="3362522181" />
```

Any thoughts on how to resolve this issue?

**Edit**
I forgot to mention that when run locally with the connection string point to the production SQL server, this is not a problem, but I will provide my `connection string` nonetheless.

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=name; User ID=user;Password=password;Integrated Security=False;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following code to my web.config fixed my issue. This overrides  the other config files on the hosting companies server for keys.

```
<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>
<roleManager enabled="false">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Answer (score 0):

Security trimming creates a controller instance for every node in the SiteMap. Although it does not interact with entity framework, dollars to donuts one or more of your controller constructors does.

To use this feature, it is important to follow a DI centric approach to controllers even if you are not actually using DI. In other words, constructors should always be simple and light - they should do nothing more than assign dependencies (whether or not you can actually pass them into the constructor). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31319843/c-sharp-mvc-site-map-very-slow-when-using-roles-very-slow#31342893) for several solutions to fixing your constructor issues.

Another possibility is that you have a custom subclass of AuthorizeAttribute that makes calls to the database. If they are not required to determine whether the user is authorized, you should defer these calls using a handler the same way Microsoft does. MvcSiteMapProvider doesn't execute the handler, but it does execute the logic that determines whether the user is authorized.

Here is a snippet of the AuthorizeAttribute from MVC 5.2 (via Reflector):

```
/* Defer execution of result to a handler */
protected virtual void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
}

public virtual void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
    }
    if (OutputCacheAttribute.IsChildActionCacheActive(filterContext))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(MvcResources.AuthorizeAttribute_CannotUseWithinChildActionCache);
    }
    if (!filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true) && !filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true))
    {
        if (this.AuthorizeCore(filterContext.HttpContext))
        {
            HttpCachePolicyBase cache = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache;
            cache.SetProxyMaxAge(new TimeSpan(0L));
            cache.AddValidationCallback(new HttpCacheValidateHandler(this.CacheValidateHandler), null);
        }
        else
        {
            this.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I meant to close this out as answered, but your first  two sentences clarify why my SQL was throwing an exception. Thanks.