# Does lots of controllers slows the performance? MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, controller

I want to ask a simple question about MVC controllers. I have googled a lot about controllers for "different controllers for each basic table", it cleared a lot of things but i have one question that i couldn't find answer for.

**My question is that if i create controller for each basic table, lets say i have 10 basic tables that would create 10 controllers. So does lots of controller slows the application performance?**

**- In case, when going from view to controller.**

**- In case, when going from controller to another controller.**

I am new so kindly be calm :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, one request is processed by one controller. And if it (cotroller) is small and have a few dependencies - it's quick. When you have one huge controller with many dependencies of other classes that have their own dependencies and so on... it could be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

## The Short Answer

No.

## The Long Answer

The *number* of controllers doesn't have as much of a performance impact as *how expensive* each controller instance is to create.

The amount of overhead you might get for the number of controllers is negligible. Although the MVC framework uses .NET Reflection to identify the current controller type, it is optimized to look in the `<Project Name>.Controllers` namespace first. But this list is cached in a file, so after the first hit the performance is pretty good.

Where you might run into performance problems is when you do heavy processing within the controller constructor. The framework creates a controller instance for *every* request, so you should make it as cheap as possible to create a controller instance. If you follow a DI-centric (dependency injection) approach even if you are not actually using DI in your project, you will be able to keep the cost of creating a controller instance to a bare minimum.

What this means in plain English is - inject your dependencies into the constructor when the controller is created only. Don't actually do any processing in the constructor, defer that for the actual Action method call.

```
public interface IHeavyProcessingService
{
    IProcessingResult DoSomethingExpensive();
}

public class HeavyProcessingService : IHeavyProcessingService
{
    public HeavyProcessingService() { 
    }

    public IProcessingResult DoSomethingExpensive() {
        // Lots of heavy processing
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300);
    }
}

public class HomeController
{
    private readonly IHeavyProcessingService heavyProcessingService;

    // The constructor does no heavy processing. It is deferred until after
    // the instance is created by HeavyProcessingService. 
    // The only thing happening here is assignment of dependencies.
    public HomeController(IHeavyProcessingService heavyProcessingService) {
        this.heavyProcessingService = heavyProcessingService
            ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(heavyProcessingService));
    };

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var result = this.heavyProcessingService.DoSomethingExpensive();

        // Do something with the result of the heavy processing

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31319843/c-sharp-mvc-site-map-very-slow-when-using-roles-very-slow#31342893) for more information.

If you *do* actually use a DI container in your application, you can improve performance even more by choosing the correct lifestyle of each dependency. If you can share the same dependency instance across multiple controller instances (singleton lifestyle), it makes the controller instance even cheaper to create.

What Backs said isn't necessarily true, either. The number of dependencies doesn't matter so much as *how expensive* those dependencies are to create. As long as the constructors are kept light and simple and the correct lifestyle is used for each dependency, performance won't be an issue regardless of the number of dependencies a controller has. That said, the controller shouldn't have more than about 5 *direct* dependencies - after that, you should [refactor to aggregate services](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/), making the dependency hierarchy more like an upside down pyramid rather than a flat set that are all injected into the controller.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the number of calls to controller.If you make frequent call to a controller for 2 to 3 table so it may get slow.Instead group that 3 table in one controller and call that.If your application needs to work in individual table than its fine,You will get response quiker.But if your application needs content from 2 to 3 tables than you have to call that 3 controller.So here the better way is to group that in one controller.
Hope you got the point